# How to display camera in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I'm trying to access the camera within the fragment in android studio.
these are the codes I wrote
My Fragment Codes:

```
    package com.example.proje.ui.camera;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import com.example.proje.ui.camera.CameraViewModel;
import com.example.proje.R;

public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {


    Camera camera;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    ShowCamera showCamera;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

        return root;


   }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        frameLayout = (FrameLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

        camera = Camera.open();

        showCamera = new ShowCamera(getContext(), camera);
        frameLayout.addView(showCamera);
    }
}
```

ShowCamera code:

```
    package com.example.proje.ui.camera;

    import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    public ShowCamera(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        this.camera = camera;
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

        if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            params.set("orientation", "portrait");
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            params.setRotation(90);
        }
        else
        {
            params.set("orientation", "landscape");
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            params.setRotation(0);
        }

        camera.setParameters(params);
        try
        {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I gave the necessary permissions from the android manifest file.
compiles seamlessly in android studio but when I run it on the phone I get the application stopped error.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a simple fragment that does the following:

1. requests permission to camera
2. then opens the camera to take photo
3. resize it by width to 1200, saves it on SD card for later upload if needed

It seems that you want only to open the camera in fragment, if so use only the needed code: openCameraIntent()
What you are trying to do is not possible (load the Camera inside FrameLayout).
the camera should be opened using startActivityForResult since it's an Activity by itself.

```
package com.example.proje.ui.camera;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;

import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;

public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

    private final int PREFERED_IMAGE_WIDTH_SIZE = 1200;

    private final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 300;
    private final int RESULT_CAMERA_LOAD_IMG = 1889;

    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private ImageView image_view;
    private Activity activity;

    private List<String> imagesFilesPaths = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

        return root;


    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        activity = getActivity();
        image_view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        frameLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);


        takePhotoFromCamera();
    }

    // THIS FUNCTION CAN BE CALLED WHENEVER YOU WANT TO TAKE NEW PHOTO
    private void takePhotoFromCamera(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        } else  {
            openCameraIntent();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE){
            if (permissions.length > 0 && grantResults.length > 0) {

                boolean flag = true;
                for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                    if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
                if (flag) {
                    openCameraIntent();
                }
            }
        }else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    private void openCameraIntent(){
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if(cameraIntent.resolveActivity(Objects.requireNonNull(activity).getPackageManager()) != null){
            //Create a file to store the image
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()),"com.smartestmedia.camerainfragment.provider", photoFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, RESULT_CAMERA_LOAD_IMG);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        imagesFilesPaths.add(image.getAbsolutePath());
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == RESULT_CAMERA_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

            String tempImageFilePath = imagesFilesPaths.get(imagesFilesPaths.size()-1);

            Uri tempImageURI = Uri.fromFile(new File( tempImageFilePath ));

            resizeThanLoadImage(tempImageFilePath, tempImageURI);

        }

    }

    private void resizeThanLoadImage(String tempImageFilePath, Uri tempImageURI){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(Objects.requireNonNull(activity).getContentResolver(), tempImageURI);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(bitmap == null)return;

        int sizeDivisor = 1;

        double imageSize = bitmap.getWidth();
        if(bitmap.getHeight() > bitmap.getWidth())imageSize = bitmap.getHeight();
        sizeDivisor = round(imageSize / PREFERED_IMAGE_WIDTH_SIZE);
        if(sizeDivisor == 0)sizeDivisor = 1;


        Bitmap bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (bitmap.getWidth()/sizeDivisor), (bitmap.getHeight()/sizeDivisor), true);

        storeBitmapInFile(bitmapScaled, tempImageFilePath);

        onImageLoaded(tempImageURI);
    }

    private int round(double d){
        double dAbs = Math.abs(d);
        int i = (int) dAbs;
        double result = dAbs - (double) i;
        if(result<0.5){
            return d<0 ? -i : i;
        }else{
            return d<0 ? -(i+1) : i+1;
        }
    }

    private void storeBitmapInFile(Bitmap image, String filePath) {
        File pictureFile = new File(filePath);
        String TAG = "TakePhotosFragment>>>> ";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void onImageLoaded(Uri imageUri) {

        // LOAD YOUR IMAGE in imageview
        image_view.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }

}
```

Good Luck!